# Can i embed a iframe into the alert box in visualforce?

Tags: visualforce, jquery, iframe

I have requirement in which on a certain condition i have to show an alert box in which i will have a link and a button. On click of the link i have to do some logic and do some DML operations. What i want to do is that i want to show a custom visualforce page having the link and button and show that page in a iframe in the alert box. 
Is this possible or i have to look other way around. Also is there anyway i can i can do this by jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you can do
Create a custom button and fill in the details and in "Behavior Section" choose "Execute JavaScript" and for "Content Source" choose "OnClick JavaScript",and in the code section paste the following code

```
 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js")}
    function showSimpleDialog(){
   var sd = new SimpleDialog("Test"+Dialogs.getNextId(), true);

   sd.setTitle("Simple Dialog");

   sd.createDialog();

   window.parent.sd = sd;  sd.setWidth("50%");
  //Specify the iFrame and give URL of VF page
    sd.setContentInnerHTML("");
```

if ($(sd.dialog).find('#InlineEditDialogX').size() == 0) {
    var close = $("<a id='InlineEditDialogX' title='Close' tabindex='0' href='javascript:void(0)' class='dialogClose'>Close</a>");

    close.mouseover(function() {

    this.className = 'dialogCloseOn';
    }).mouseout(function() {
    this.className = 'dialogClose';
    }).click(function() {

    // finally our on click handler which closes the dialog
    sd.hide();
    });
    // insert the new generated close button before the h2 tag so it'll show up on the top right corner
    close.insertBefore($(sd.dialog).find('.topLeft h2'));  
    } sd.show(); } showSimpleDialog();

This will bring up a modal where you can display your visual force page through iFrame and further through controller you can do all the DML operations.

Comment: Thanks Pawan. This is exactly something that i wanted. But in the sd.setContentInnerHTML(""); when i am putting my iframe in the this, in the src attribute of it i can't enter my complete url coz it's having paprameter's as well. Can you please tell me how could i make this url work.??  i.e. my url is something lyk this /apex/testpage?id='a1234567890789'&name='test'   
Can you please help me on this..

Comment: done it(just have to add the +url+ in the url). Thanks. The solution works as per my requirement.

Comment: How can i close the dialog box from my iframe's VF page. And re-render my parent VF page to new href from the child VF page(i.e. in the iFrame).

Comment: You cant close it with iframe's VF page
What you can do is after "sd.hide" type "window.location.reload(true)" this will refresh the parent page

Answer (score 4):

You can't use JavaScript's `alert` function, but you could create a popup div element that contains the logic you would like to use. One sound method for this would be something like a [Lightbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightbox_%28JavaScript%29), where the content would be hosted in a fixed position, z-indexed div that hovers over the rest of the page content. There are *numerous* examples for this online. I've personally used this on several occasions with success, although I don't have a convenient example I can copy and paste. The iframe isn't strictly necessary, since you could just graft the DOM elements directly into the Visualforce page's DOM, but that is purely a matter of preference.

Comment: Pretty neat solution for sure. Thanks.
One thing also i want to add that isn't it possible by some other means i could do this functionality.(without adding the lightbox js and images in my static folder) a built in thing for salesforce or in javascript.

Comment: @NaveenRaw Not sure if this is a clarification question, but in short, yes, there is no publicly available, Salesforce-native means of accomplishing your goal. Salesforce uses lightboxes for inline editing, etc, but these aren't publicly documented and can't be relied on. You do not need to use a static resource and/or a library; I've written a lightbox in just a couple dozen lines of code, it's not hard.

Comment: Okay. will try that. one day will catch up with you on making such fine coding of writing lightbox in only dozen of lines !.. thanks.